# Simplified SASS selectors for child pseudo elements?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying (and have succeeded) in selecting a div, it's child, and it's pseudo before/after elements, using the following syntax, but I want to know if there is a **simplified way of doing it?**

After some research I found the following scss works for the html/scss (link to JSFiddle is below also):

**HTML**

*Want to add a class `all-borders-hidden` to `reveal-div` element, which will then make the div itself, it's child/children, and both pseudo elements update to have no border:*

```html
<div class="reveal-div">
  Parent Div
  <div class="main-image-div"> 
                     Main Cild Div
     </div>
</div>
```

**scss**

```css
.reveal-div {

    border: 2px solid black;
    // I toggle the all-borders-hidden class on the parent/ancestor
    // reveal-div class element
    // The following works, but it's a bit verbose - can it be simplified
    &.all-borders-hidden {
        border: none;
    }
    &.all-borders-hidden *{
        border: none;
    }
    &.all-borders-hidden::after{
        border: none;
    }
    &.all-borders-hidden::before{
        border: none;
    }
}
```

I have the [exmaple running in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6541k18/10/)

[image: Example on JSFiddle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&` again:

```
.reveal-div {

    border: 2px solid black;
    // I toggle the all-borders-hidden class on the parent/ancestor
    // reveal-div class element
    // The following works, but it's a bit verbose - can it be simplified
    &.all-borders-hidden {
        border: none;
        * {
            border: none;
        }
        &::after{
            border: none;
        }
        &::before{
            border: none;
        }
    }
}
```

and if they are sharing the `border:none` you can do this:

```
.reveal-div {

    border: 2px solid black;
    // I toggle the all-borders-hidden class on the parent/ancestor
    // reveal-div class element
    // The following works, but it's a bit verbose - can it be simplified
    &.all-borders-hidden {
        &,
        *,
        &::before,
        &::after{
            border: none;
        }
    }
}
```