# Sass comma separated pseudo-elements for browser compatibility

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to write a single rule for all browser pseudo-elements in type=range input separated by commas, but realised it's not working in my case

```
//this works
input[type="range"] {
  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 2px;
  }
}

//this doesn't
input[type="range"] {
  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, &::-ms-track, &::-moz-range-track {
    height: 2px;
  }
}
```

Googling shows that some applications of this work like here [Simplified SASS selectors for child pseudo elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431176/simplified-sass-selectors-for-child-pseudo-elements)
But maybe the case is in my sass version, or I can't use it with this kind of pseudos?

Comment: FWIW, in my experience Safari has trouble parsing comma-separated pseudo-classes/elements.

Comment: FYI, your exact syntax works as expected for me. I'm using Compass 1.0.3.

Comment: Your Sass should compile to CSS without any problem. However, browsers will not apply styles if any of the selectors in the list are invalid. `height: 2px` will never get applied because no single browser uses all of those proprietary selectors.

Comment: This is not a problem with SASS probably. It is how CSS works if that answer is right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982449/why-isnt-it-possible-to-combine-vendor-specific-pseudo-elements-classes-into-on